# Got 2 ways to store objects into MongoDB, one with destructuring the req.body and one without. Why destructuring then?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I am coding along with a video that makes an event creation app.
In the video the guys writes the controller for the posts to e saved into Atlas cluster like this:

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags } = req.body;
  const newPostMessage = new PostMessage({ title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags })
  try {
      await newPostMessage.save();
      res.status(201).json(newPostMessage );
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

and I wrote it without destructuring the body:

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const post = req.body;
  const newPost = new PostMessage(post);
  try {
    await newPost.save();
    res.status(201).json(newPost)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
};
```

In the database, I see the 2 results being saved exactly the same. What is the difference here then? Why would I want to destruct the req.body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just personal preference. Sometimes it's just more convenient to use destructuring.